# Nested parameters causes kSOAP2 to produce an error

Tags: android, ksoap2

I'm trying to send a SoapObject with nested parameters, but it's producing an error, despite the fact that I'm following the guideline from kSOAP...

I have no problem sending a SoapObject without nested parameters, but as soon as I have to send nested, it crashes.... (with the only difference being the nested parameters)...

Here is how I set up the request:

```
void connection()
{
    Singleton service = Singleton.getInstance();
    String firstURL = service.getURL();
    URL = firstURL + "Attendance.svc";

    //Get parentID, parentToken
    String parentIDSingleton = service.getParentID();
    String parentTokenSingleton = service.getParentToken();

    //Get current time for GMT
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    //Set format
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

    //Save in string
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());      

    //Initialize soap request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapObject nestedParameters = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "planInfos");

    //Add parameters
    request.addProperty("nAttendeeId", "*some value");

    //Add nested parameters
    nestedParameters.addProperty("day:Date", formattedDate);
    nestedParameters.addProperty("day:PlannedStatus", "Syg");
    request.addSoapObject(nestedParameters);

    //Declare the version of the SOAP request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.implicitTypes=true;
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);

    //Prepare request
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    //Set up the header
    Element parentID = new Element().createElement("ns", "parentId");
    parentID.addChild(Node.TEXT, parentIDSingleton);
    Element parentToken = new Element().createElement("ns", "parentToken");
    parentToken.addChild(Node.TEXT, parentTokenSingleton);
    Element authType = new Element().createElement("ns", "authType");
    authType.addChild(Node.TEXT, "Parent");
    Element kindergardenID = new Element().createElement("ns", "id");
    kindergardenID.addChild(Node.TEXT, "1");

    //Add the header
    Element header[] = {parentID, parentToken, authType, kindergardenID};
    envelope.headerOut = header;

    //Needed to make the internet call
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    //Allow for debugging - needed to output the request
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try 
    {
        //this is the actual part that will call the web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        //Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.            
        SoapObject sResult = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

    } catch(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException ex2)
    {               
        System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.requestDump.toString());

    }  catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.requestDump.toString());
    }
}
```

On the [kSOAP2 website](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks) they say to set up nested parameters like this:

```
SoapObject users = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "users");
SoapObject john = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "user");
john.addProperty("name", "john");
john.addProperty("age", 12);
SoapObject marie = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "user");
john.addProperty("name", "marie");
john.addProperty("age", 27);
users.addSoapObject(john);
users.addSoapObject(marie);
```

Which is what I do...

Any ideas???

The errors I'm getting:

> 05-03 10:46:45.313: W/System.err(1855): java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   kindergardentest.sms2go.dk 05-03 10:46:45.329: W/System.err(1855):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506) 05-03
>
> 10:46:45.329: W/System.err(1855):     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294) 05-03
>
> 10:46:45.329: W/System.err(1855):     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256) 05-03
>
> 10:46:45.329: W/System.err(1855):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:69)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.347: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:48)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.347: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.347: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.347: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.347: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.347: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.371: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.371: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:153)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.371: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.371: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   com.cim.daycare.AuthenticateConnection.connection(AuthenticateConnection.java:74)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.377: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   com.cim.daycare.DayCareActivity$AuthenticateUser.doInBackground(DayCareActivity.java:308)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.377: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   com.cim.daycare.DayCareActivity$AuthenticateUser.doInBackground(DayCareActivity.java:1)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.377: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) 05-03 10:46:45.377:
>   W/System.err(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.377: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 05-03
>
> 10:46:45.377: W/System.err(1855):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.388: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.388: W/System.err(1855):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 05-03 10:46:45.388:
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.407: W/dalvikvm(1855): threadid=9: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1855): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 05-03
>
> 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855): java.lang.RuntimeException: An
>   error occured while executing doInBackground()
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 05-03
>
> 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 05-03 10:46:45.420:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1855): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   com.cim.daycare.DayCareActivity$AuthenticateUser.doInBackground(DayCareActivity.java:311)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   com.cim.daycare.DayCareActivity$AuthenticateUser.doInBackground(DayCareActivity.java:1)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>
> 05-03 10:46:45.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   ... 4 more 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855): Activity
>   com.cim.daycare.DayCareActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40517918 that
>   was originally added here
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cim.daycare.DayCareActivity
>   has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40517918 that
>   was originally added here
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):
>     at android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:258) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697:
>   E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   com.cim.daycare.DayCareActivity$AuthenticateUser.onPreExecute(DayCareActivity.java:295)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697:
>   E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   com.cim.daycare.DayCareActivity.onCreate(DayCareActivity.java:154)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697:
>   E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697:
>   E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>
> 05-03 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 05-03
>
> 10:46:47.697: E/WindowManager(1855):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Add your manifest file this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and try again.